# Go unmarshall XML

Tags: xml, go

I currently have the following XML

```
<monster name="Valkyrie" nameDescription="a valkyrie" race="blood" experience="85" speed="190" manacost="450">
    <health now="190" max="190" />
    <look type="139" head="113" body="57" legs="95" feet="113" corpse="20523" />
    <voices interval="5000" chance="10">
        <voice sentence="Another head for me!" />
        <voice sentence="Head off!" />
        <voice sentence="Your head will be mine!" />
        <voice sentence="Stand still!" />
        <voice sentence="One more head for me!" />
    </voices>
</monster>
```

And I am reading it using the following structs

```
type monster struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"monster"`
    Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
    NameDescription string `xml:"nameDescription,attr"`
    Race string `xml:"race,attr"`
    Experience int `xml:"experience,attr"`
    Speed int `xml:"speed,attr"`
    ManaCost int `xml:"manacost,attr"`
    Health monsterHealth `xml:"health"`
    Look monsterLook `xml:"look"`
    Voices monsterVoice `xml:"voices"`
}

type monsterVoice struct {
    Voices []monsterSentence
}

type monsterSentence struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"voice"`
    Sentence string `xml:"sentence,attr"`
}

type monsterLook struct {
    Type int `xml:"type,attr"`
    Head int `xml:"head,attr"`
    Body int `xml:"body,attr"`
    Legs int `xml:"legs,attr"`
    Feet int `xml:"feet,attr"`
    Corpse int `xml:"corpse,attr"`
}

type monsterHealth struct {
    Now int `xml:"now,attr"`
    Max int `xml:"max,attr"`
}
```

But I am not sure how to read the voices element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed to specify XML element mapping for `Voices` :

```
type monsterVoice struct {
    Voices []monsterSentence `xml:"voice"`
}
```

after that small addition, unmarshalling as usual should work :

```
var result monster
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(your_xml_data_string), &result)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
for _, r := range result.Voices.Voices {
    fmt.Println(r.Sentence)
}
```

**<kbd>[`playground demo 1`](https://play.golang.org/p/_phbETNCSh)</kbd>**

better yet, drop `monsterVoice` and use child selector like so :

```
type monster struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"monster"`
    ....
    Voices []monsterSentence `xml:"voices>voice"`
}
```

Then we can get rid of the awkward `result.Voices.Voices` in the previous demo :

```
for _, r := range result.Voices {
    fmt.Println(r.Sentence)
}
```

**<kbd>[`playground demo 2`](https://play.golang.org/p/QQMsTyzXnt)</kbd>**

**output :** (both demo yields the same output)

```
Another head for me!
Head off!
Your head will be mine!
Stand still!
One more head for me!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `xml.Unmarshal(xmlString, data)`

Here is complete example of xml unmarshalling https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/example_test.go